# git diff exclude merge - commits

Tags: git, gitlab, diff, commit

I'm trying to list all changed files inside branch FEATURE-1 ignoring it's merge commits to the branch DEV, from which it was originally created using git diff. So the graph looks like this:

```
         x---y---z---w---feature
        /   /   /
---a---b---c-+-d-+-e---dev
```

and when i'm on y commit, and type

```
git diff --name-only dev...feature
```

i get right what i need. But after merging feature branch into dev, imagine we are on w now, using this command i get blank output. So i need to exclude somehow all merge commits from git diff. Is there any way to exclude such commits? thanks in advance.

I use git version 2.21.0.windows.1
Windows 10, for local project

Answer (score 0):

**Outdated answer** (see comments)

Just reference the commit before the merge instead of `dev`

```
git diff --name-only <commit e>...feature
```

(if the merge commit is the last one on `dev`, you can just use `HEAD^` instead of first searching for the hash in the branch's log)

---

**Edit after comments :**

It seems your graph is more like this :

```
      X---Y---Z <<< feature
     /     \   \ 
A---B-------C---D---E <<< dev
```

Comment: but if i have several merges? Not only one

Comment: @DenisBabichev Can you try to update your graph to help us have a better view of the situation?

Comment: What is confusing is that although you're describing merging `feature` into `dev`, your graph shows the contrary : merges from `dev` to `feature`. So which is it? Also, the "+" are not quite clear. What commit is the merge commit, hard to say from here.

Comment: sorry, i don't know standarts for git - graph drawings, my fault. All the merges are from feature to dev. y - commit correspondes to c-commit, z-commit correspondes to d-commit.

Comment: I'll have to question you again, sorry :-) When you say "corresponds to", does it mean that `c` is the commit merge that was created by merging `y` into `dev` from `feature`? If so, I'll help you redraw the graph.

Comment: @DenisBabichev I updated to suggest a new graph, but I must admit the situation is quite unclear to me at this point, I hope it'll help others to understand it quicker.

Comment: Also worth noting: `git diff A...B` (three dots) has Git find the merge base(s) of A and B. If this is just one commit `MB`, the result is equivalent to `git diff MB B`. If there is more than one merge base commit, `git diff` misbehaves. Run `git merge-base --all A B` to see the merge base(s).